# Flutter GetX variable changes but UI does not

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have two RxLists containing custom models:

```
var openDepartures = RxList<Departure>([]);
var finishedDepartures = RxList<Departure>([]);
```

I bind a stream to populate these RxLists with values from firebase. Since my Stream(which I am binding to the variables) changes according to the user's choice, I bind the new stream to the same variable, but since that would result in two streams controlling one variable, I "reset" the variable before that:

```
openDepartures = RxList<Departure>();
finishedDepartures = RxList<Departure>();
....
openDepartures.bindStream(
  Database().getOpenDepartures(
    userController.userLocation.value,
  ),
);
finishedDepartures.bindStream(
  Database().getFinishedDepartures(
    userController.userLocation.value,
  ),
);
```

The problem is that the UI is not refreshing, but when I do not "reset" the variables, everything works fine. What's weird as well is that the variable does get populated with the correct data. It is just not shown in the UI.

#### What I have tried to fix that:

- update() method
- Get.reloadAll()
- call .refresh() on the variables
- disposing and initializing the controller again

My question is now, how do I get the screen to refresh, or does anyone have an idea how to bind a new stream without "resetting" the old one and having multiple streams on one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **finally** solved my problem. The underlying problem was that I was binding multiple streams to one variable and therefore the variable was updated whenever one of the streams fired. The solution was the following:

- Create an `RxList` of the variable:

`final _openDepartureList = RxList<RxList<Departure>>();`

- Create a getter for the last element of that list:

`RxList<Departure> get openDepartures => _openDepartureList.last;`

- Remove the old items:

```
if (_openDepartureList.length >= 2) {
  _openDepartureList.removeRange(0, _openDepartureList.length - 1);
}
```

- Add an empty `RxList` to the List

`_openDepartureList.add(RxList.empty());`

- Bind the stream to the last element of the List, hence the one just added

`_openDepartureList.last.bindStream():`

That was it! I now always have the right stream bound to the variable I want and do not have multiple streams controlling one variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `update()` like
`void() { foo = newData; update(); }`

or use ProgressIndicator
like
`RxBool loading = false.obs`

`void Foo() { loading.value = true; your logic... loading.value = false; }`

and use `controller.loading.value` in UI for check progress and show when loading is complete

Comment: have tried that, does sadly not work :(

Comment: yes, this often doesn't work for me either, try using a loading indicator for force screen reload

Comment: How would a loading indicator result in the UI being updated?

Comment: i edited answer, check please

Comment: The problem is that I have nothing to load. I have a stream of data continuously coming from firebase, but somehow the UI is not updated when I reset the variables to a new RxType

Comment: try watching a variable with `NotifyListener()` or Stream, no more ideas (